# Trying to concat an array of multiple array into one array

Tags: javascript

I try to concat Array of multiple Arrays like this

```
`let soldNumber = [
 [1,2],
 [5,7],
 [35,67],
 ...
]`
```

to recieve this `let soldNumber = [1,2,5,7,35,67,...]`

Comment: `soldNumber.flat()`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=concat+multiple+arrays+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

`soldNumber.flat()`

[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score -1):

```
   let soldNumber = [[1,2], [5,7], [35,67]];
   let newSoldNumber = soldNumber.flat();
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, please explain your answer so as to help others too..